Microsoft Graph Api - Get License Details
I want to get LicenseDetail information about users in my organization. I have to send several Api request(users/userid/licenseDetails) to do this but what i want to do is send only one request. How can I do that?
I want to get list of user information with license information by only one request.

Unfortunately this isn't supported.
You can only request the license details of each user individually by calling
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/licenseDetails (documentation)
Or you can get an overview of all licenses and their numbers by calling
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus (documenation)
